# Normal websites use large amounts of RAM

Tags: safari, memory, google-chrome

Lately, on my MacBook Pro, visiting webpages has started to consume large amounts of RAM. Visiting websites like Stack Overflow, golang.org, golang playground, or gnu website causes my computer to perform very poorly since it runs out of RAM.

This occurs on both Safari or Chrome. Some of those websites are and most of them use no flash or any other plug in as far as I can detect.

What can be the reason for such a behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that the reason was some adware, malware infected my web browsers. They were making network requests initiated without my permission.

I have installed AdwareMedic and it completely solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let us know the cause / solution!

Comment: Though It has been a time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on OSX Yosemite? There were some changes that allow the OS and by extension Safari to make use of your computers whole amount of RAM, the mantra being that unused RAM is being wasted.

Not too sure what it means for a low RAM system, I would assume that apps would unload some data from the RAM when it is nearing full.

Keep in mind that although the websites may seem straightforward, they are vastly more complex than even a year or two ago, so over time the amount of RAM needed with increase

Comment: Before this happens I had installed the Yosemite for 8 months. Nothing like that has happened before.